# Combine multiple latest version of observable, ngrx

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5, ngrx

I have a `product` which has `comments`, `attachments`, `images` attached to it. All those items are taken from a `ngrx` store which means all those items are observables. My question is how do I combine those items ?

Usually what I do is use :

```js
combineLatest(selectProducts, selectProductComments, (products, comments) => {
  // attach comments to products here
})
```

However `combineLatest` works with 2 sets of observable and I have 4 of them. So what's the simplest way to go about this ?

---

Here is more context :

So we display a list of `products`, when each product is clicked more info on the product are loaded and displayed in a popup. Those info contain the `comments`, `attachments` and `images`. This step can be called the `DEEP_LOADING` phase where when the user clicks on a products, the comments, attachments and images are loaded via http.

The user can also add new images, comments or attachments. When he does so, a `comment` with its status `pending` set to true is added to the list of comments. When the http request resolves this `comment` pending property is set to false.

When the user close the popup and opens a new product then the new `comments`, `attachments` and `images` are loaded. When this time he closes the popup and opens the first one he opened, the `comments` that are displayed are the ones that are loaded from the backend ( same as before) but also the pending comments if any.

The comment reducer might look like this: ( I say might because I'm in the process of normalizing my store, the comments are part of the product at the moment and thus I don't need to care about the pending stuff..)

```js
export function commentReducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_COMMENT':
            // when we set we have to keep the pending comments,
            // so when we open another product, then switch back to the original one
            // if the pending comment is still pending it should display as pending
            const newState = state.filter((c: AppComment) => c.pending);
            newState.push(action.payload);
            return newState;
        case 'CLEAR':
            return initialState;
    }
}
```

Comment: combineLatest can take X arguments. You can pass as many as you want.

Comment: Also, are you expecting one trigger or to keep the observable running? Because combineLatest can be dangerous. You might want to take a look into withLatestFrom and if it fits your needs use this one. (if you have no idea, just give more context)

Comment: @Maxime I added a bit more context. Is that the type of context you wanted ?

Comment: @Maxime if I understand `withLatestFrom` correctly then I won't have the comments displayed when I open the popup.

Comment: Why do you need to combine them? Why not subscribe to each separately and let the view "attach" them?

Comment: @YourGoodFriend good point, I think that might be doable. It's still interesting for convenience though, so I can have 1 selector that does the job of selecting the whole thing instead of using multiples.

Comment: @Maxime maybe answer the question with your first comment ? So I can close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`combineLatest` can take X arguments. You can pass as many as you want.

For example:

```
combineLatest(v1$, v2$, v3$, v4$, (v1, v2, v3, v4) => {
  console.log(v1, v2, v3, v4);
})
```